# QGIS Layering DWG

Tags: qgis

I am a completely newbie when it comes to this software. I have been learning for the past 3 weeks though and unable to find the answer to this question. I searched high and low, either I'm missing it, or going crazy. Steep learning curve with this software.

Info QGIS 3.8.0 w/GRASS 7, raster data is DEM from WEBODM on 36 acre development in North MS, USA. Vector data is a DWG with NO coordinates. Also have shapefile with 2 points marking known locations on the DWG layout.

I have imported the raster and it lines up perfectly with Open Street Map, I load the shapefile and it lines up perfectly with Open Street Map and raster, I load the DWG and it places it into the center of the Open Street Map layer.

I have coordinate captured the known shapefile point and the known point on the layout and subtracted everything and use v.transform to move it, everytime it move it slightly differently, but never close enough (China, or a few cities away, or Texas)
Is QGIS the best way to do this? How can I add the known point data into the DWG to make it import correctly?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the coordinate system of the DWG is in - right click on layer, Set CRS --> Set Layer CRS... Otherwise QGIS doesn't know in which coordinate system to plot.

Comment: Yes I have, I've used every available CRS Projection Available for my area.

Comment: Because you are having trouble you could manually align the dwg. First make sure that your project and your layer is in the same crs. It should be a local crs like MS state plane. Then Turn on editing for your dwg  layer and select the entire layer and move it to one of your known points. Then do the same thing with rotate and scale until it is lined up. The documentation has short cut keys for setting the rotation point etc. Make sure you then double check other points

Answer (score 1):

Few things to try:

1. You can try Vector Bender plugin, which may help you with translation.
2. As you have known point. Move your DWG drawing in correct location and import that dwg to QGIS in correct CRS Projection.